VSphere 8.0 disabling Virtualization Based Security for Windows Server 2022
How do I disable Virtualization Based Security VBS in Windows Server 2022? All I see is links for Windows 11.
When I attempt VMotion it fails with the message:
"This machine or version of VMware ESX does not support the virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT features required by this virtual machine. Resume the checkpoint on a machine that supports the required virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT features. Failed to receive migration"
I disabled the group policy "Turn on virtualization based security".
Core isolation memory integrity is disabled.
Secure boot is disabled.
Hyper-V is not installed.
VBS registry value is disabled.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.hostclient.doc/GUID-B41F1783-F8F6-4E07-B7E1-316E2241EA36.html have you tried this?

yes, I do that but I still get the same error message above.
